# Long Run Time in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services

I was writing a program for manual confusion matrix. I had to loop over 10K iterations.

```
df_a=df_a.sort_values('proba')
tpr_lst=[]
fpr_lst=[]
for i in tqdm(df_a['proba']): #df_a['proba'] contains 10K points, each point will be taken a new threshold to determine y_pred is 0 or 1, all this is too plot an ROC.
    def y_pred_auc(x):
        if x<i:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
    df_a['y_pred_auc']=df_a['proba'].map(y_pred_auc)
    df_a['con_mat_label_auc']=df_a[['y','y_pred']].apply(confusion_matrix,axis=1)
    tp_count=len(df_a['con_mat_label_auc']=='TP')
    fp_count=len(df_a['con_mat_label_auc']=='FP')
    tn_count=len(df_a['con_mat_label_auc']=='TN')
    fn_count=len(df_a['con_mat_label_auc']=='FN')

    tpr_auc=tp_count/(tp_count+fn_count)
    fpr_auc=fp_count/(tn_count+fp_count)

    tpr_lst.append(tpr_auc)
    fpr_lst.append(fpr_auc)
```

This code is taking about a hour even on c4 AWS Sagemaker instance. Is there anyway to optimse this code or can anyone suggest a fast AWS Sagemaker instance I have tried Colab as well its worse over there.

Answer (score 0):

Sagemaker ml.p2.xlarge or use p2.xlarge.

Stop the instance after using to avoid over paying.

https://course.fast.ai/start_sagemaker.html